# Has anyone noticed strange UIPasteboard behaviour when using apps which integrate Google services?

Tags: ios, admob, firebase-analytics

I just opened an iOS app (App Store version) I made which includes the Google AdMob and Firebase SDKs. As the app was loading, I saw the standard iOS alert for pasting contents from iCloud's Universal Clipboard feature. My understanding is that this happens when a user retrieves `UIPasteboard` contents, mainly via the "Paste" menu item in `UITextInput` controls.

I know for certain that none of the first-party code references `UIPasteboard`, and no user interaction could have triggered this. My fear is that one of these analytics services is retrieving the contents of the pasteboard, which I would think is egregious.

Does anyone have any experiences with this or recommendations to resolve it?